# How to clone a subset of git branches

Tags: git, gitlab

I am cloning from a repo with >1000 branches. I want to clone the master branch and a single feature branch (and nothing else).

I know I can clone just the feature branch by running

```
git clone git@url_for_git_repo.com --single-branch --branch feature_branch_name
```

but then I don't have access to the master branch. How can I add the master branch to my local repo now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git remote` to add individual branches.  For instance, if you cloned the single branch `branch1` but really want five remote-tracking names for `origin/master`, `origin/branch1`, `origin/branch2`, ..., `origin/branch4`:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin master branch2 branch3 branch4
```

would do the trick.

(You can also manually edit the `.git/config` file, or run `git config --edit`, if you're comfortable manipulating the configuration file that way.)

Note that `set-branches --add` is very different from plain `add`; the latter adds an additional remote, rather than adding branches to one particular single-branch remote.  Also, `set-branches` *without* `--add` means *discard the existing remote-tracking names, and change to single-branch mode for the specified branches*.

(It's kind of unfortunate that Git uses the word *remote* to mean one thing, and *remote-tracking branch* or what I call *remote-tracking name* to mean another quite different thing.  It gets very confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could ask for it specifically with

```
git fetch origin master
```